# What is the right approach for using casper and phantom js for automated UI testing?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, automated-tests, frontend, casperjs

I have 200 manual test cases which I want to automate for UI testing I have selected Casper framework and Phantom JS for this.

Below is sample test case for home page.

```
/**

* homepage.js - Homepage tests.

*/

var test = "abc";

casper.test.begin('homepage', 5, function suite(test) {

   casper.start("url", function() {

        test.assertTitle("Title abc", "title is the one expected");

        test.assertEval(function() {

            return __utils__.findAll("nav.top-fly-out-nav > ul > li > a").length < 8;

        }, "7  navigation link found");

        test.assertExists('form[action="/search"]', "Search form found");

        this.fill('form[action="/search"]', {

            keyword: "clear"

        }, true);

        this.click('#bws-s-search-btn');

        this.waitForSelector('.bws-detail-listing',

            function pass () {

                test.pass("Searh result page loaded}");

            },

            function fail () {

                test.fail("Searh result page not loaded");

            }

        );

    });

    casper.then(function() {

        test.assertTitle("Search", "title is ok");

        test.assertUrlMatch(/keyword=clear/, "search has been submitted");

        test.assertEval(function() {

            return __utils__.findAll(".bws-detail-listing article").length > 0;

        }, "search result found");

    });


    casper.run(function() {

        test.done();

    });

});
```

I want to ask following questions.

1)  What is the right approach for writing test cases like currently all test values are hard coded in test case like navigation count , title etc... How I can keep test values in Json?

2) How I can execute 10 different module test cases like test1.js test2.js one by one.

3) How I can log test result in a text file?

4) Is this the right way to create test module is the correct Architecture.

Comment: Here are 4 questions that together are too broad to write about in a single answer. Also, all of them are distinct and do not depend on each other. Please ask a separate question for each of them (except the last one, because it's primarily opinion-based).

Comment: 1. dunno, 2. [this](https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/blob/master/samples/multirun.js), 3. with [phantomjs`fs` module](http://phantomjs.org/api/fs/), 4.  [extending casperjs](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/extending.html), and lastly pls do what @ArtjomB. said.